# overlap and save method) relation zero padding with double size FIR filter coefficient

Tags: dft, time-frequency, zero-padding, overlap-save

i'm doing overlap and save method at frequency domain
to do this, i added one block back and forth at filter and signal respectly
The problem is
my filter is bessel function and that is look like this[image]
but zero padded bessel function filter is [image]
when i using this padded filter, distortion arise at certain frequency
i can control tap size

i know in time domain convolution, zero padding prevent circular convolution
but also in frequency domain, zero padding means increase frequency resolution
i think 200(filter tap)+200(zero padding)tap and 400tap with exact filter is not differenct so i can use 400tap filter not zero padded although circular convolution in time domain is distorted.

my question is when i'm doing overlap and save method, is it okay to use 400 tap not use 200(filter)+200(zero padding)filter although circular convolution is distorted in time domain?

Please help me....

Comment: Please label the axes of your graph. Is this time or frequency domain data ?

Comment: x : frequency y: abs value      gragh means transfer function of filter